# How to do enrichment analysis with scipy.stats.hypergeom.sf function

Tags: python, statistics, scipy

I want to do pathway enrichment analysis in python using `scipy.stats.hypergeom.sf function` to select pathways that are significantly enriched in at least one tissue.

my data:

```
Enrichment  CANCER_TYPE PATHWAY
11.6    Breast Carcinoma    Cell cycle/DNA replication
2   Breast Carcinoma    Protein stability and degradation/DNA replication
2.8 Breast Carcinoma    EGFR signaling/DNA replication
4   Breast Carcinoma    p53 pathway/DNA replication
0   Breast Carcinoma    PI3K/MTOR signaling/DNA replication
1.2 Pancreatic Carcinoma    Mitosis/RTK signaling
3.3 Pancreatic Carcinoma    EGFR signaling/RTK signaling
```

Comment: what is "Enrichment"? usually this kind of data comes in the form of a list of genes with annotations and some sort of background set of annotations for genes in a genome. At a minimum, we would expect some count of genes/gene annotations, which is necessary to get the numbers to plug into a hypergeometric test. Different tools will count annotations differently, perhaps tell us more about where your data table comes from?

Comment: Could you please add some more detail to your question? Context helps a lot. It's great that you've included input data, but we don't know how that data is generated, or what the 'Enrichment' field means.